# Selenium 2 Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

How can we make a batch file for executing Selenium Webdriver projects in Java?

I am able to make Executable jar files By File> Export> Java> Runnable jar, but Want to make the BATCH File.

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch file cannot be made out of a jar. What you can do is make the jar file and have it called from the batch file. You can make a batch file and use command "java -jar Jar_File_Name", now when you run the batch file the jar is executed.

Comment: Thanks... I am able to run the Jar file. Is there any possibility to convert selenium code in Batch File?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.jadeliquid.com/blogs/2011/running-selenium-tests-from-the-command-line.php). Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, you could check some other test frameworks like [WATIR](http://watir.com/). I found this really better and faster to develop than selenium.